# In Wing IDE 101 4.1 how can I have outputs to shell in real-time?

Tags: python, shell, user-interface, ide

In Wing IDE 101 4.1 how can I have outputs to shell in real-time ?
I have a GUI application like blow:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QMainWindow ,QApplication
from final_gui import final_gui

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, final_gui):
    def __init__(self,*args):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args)

        self.setupUi(self)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

print ("print me")

window = MainWindow()
ui = MainWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

"print me" statement print in shell after I close my GUI application window.

or I should think about another IDE?

Comment: I found out i should use debug instead of run  ;)

Answer (score 0):

In Wing 4 output may not appear until the block of code you're executing completes (in the shells, not the debugger which works fine).  This has been fixed in Wing 101 version 5, so try that instead:  http://wingware.com/downloads/wingide-101/5/binaries